# Finding elements related by attributes with emphasis on one of the elements

Tags: xml, xpath, xpath-1.0

I'm trying to find a way to make sure that if an element with certain attribute values are present in the XML that they have a matching different element using XPath.

I'm working on a Data Validator for information that my organization sends out.  One of the validations I need to perform is that if there is an Description element in container 2 that has an Description Type element with a Word Attribute that is GNC, there needs to be an Item element with a Item Type element container 1 that has the same internal ID value and a Word value of C or G.

Sample XML:

```
<Root>
<Container1 ID="38715795">
    <Item ID="119479" InternalID="2090205">
        <ItemType Word="C">A Value</ItemType>
    </Item>
    <Item ID="119480" InternalID="2090206">
        <ItemType Word="NP">B Value</ItemType>
    </Item>
    <Item ID="175656" InternalID="2137464">
        <ItemType Word="C">A Value</ItemType>
    </Item>
</Container1>
<Container2 ID="38715802">
    <Description ID="119479" InternalID="2090205">
        <DescriptionType Word="GNC">Description Z</DescriptionType>
    </Description>
    <Description ID="119480" InternalID="2090206">
        <DescriptionType Word="P">Description W</DescriptionType>
    </Description>
    <Description ID="175656" InternalID="2137464">
        <DescriptionType Word="P">Description Z</DescriptionType>
    </Description>
</Container2>
</Root>
```

I think I am fairly close.  After a lot of looking and Google Foo, I discovered XPath functions. The following gets me close:

```
boolean(/Root/Container2/Description/@InternalID[../DescriptionType/@Word = 'GNC'] != /Root/Container1/Item/@InternalChargeID[../ItemType/@Word = "C" or ../ItemType/@Word = "G"])
```

The problem is that it is possible for there to be a Item element that has a C or G Word value with no matching Description value and that is okay.  The situation in the sample XML should be okay but the path is returning true instead of false.  What I need to find is a way to check if there is an Item element for every Description element without caring about if there is a Description element for every Item element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because your xpath on the right side:

```
/Root/Container1/Item/@InternalChargeID[../ItemType/@Word = "C" or ../ItemType/@Word = "G"]
```

matches both

```
<Item ID="119479" InternalID="2090205">

<Item ID="175656" InternalID="2137464">
```

this xpath returns false:

```
boolean(/Root/Container2/Description[DescriptionType/@Word = 'GNC']/@InternalID !=
    /Root/Container1/Item[@InternalID = 
/Root/Container2/Description[DescriptionType/@Word =
    'GNC']/@InternalID][ItemType/@Word = 'C' or ItemType/@Word = 'G']/@InternalID)
```

it adds a predicate to `Item` nodes with the same `@InternalID`

Comment: Thank you!!  I knew that it had to be something small.  I have been looking at it for so long, I just couldn't see the issue.